# Is an array an object in Java?

Tags: java

In Java we can declare an array using the following:

```
String[] array = new String[10]; 
int size = array.length;
```

Does this mean that the array itself is an object?
I ask, because in C++ an array is just a pointer and does not have any methods.

Comment: No, in C++ an array is an array, and not not an array.

Comment: `if (array instanceof Object) System.out.println("Yes!")`

Comment: Oh, and in C++, both arrays and pointers are objects.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes All C++ arrays are C++ objects indeed, but there are C++ pointers which are not C++ objects, namely all pointers which are the result of evaluating an rvalue. Examples include `&x`, `p+i` and `new int(42)`.

Comment: @skaffman The message is not strictly necessary, since it wouldn't compile otherwise.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Yes.

The Java Language Specification [section 4.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) starts off with:

> An object is a class instance or an array.

Comment: Until now I always assumed an object was synonymous with class instance and that arrays were a special language feature or something.

Comment: Detailed explanation is given here:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-primitive-type-object-java/

Answer (score 64):

Yes; the Java Language Specification [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html):

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

Comment: If array is an object, doesn't that mean it is an instance of a class? If so, can I extend that class?

Comment: No, it doesn't: The Java spec [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1): "An object is a class instance or an array. A class instance is explicitly created by a class instance creation expression (§15.9). An array is explicitly created by an array creation expression (§15.10). ". And no, you can not extend an array, because the extends clause [must](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) feature a ClassType.

Answer (score 41):

Well, let's ask Java!

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(args instanceof Object);
    int[] someIntegers = new int[] {42};
    System.out.println(someIntegers instanceof Object);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

Comment: You can also declare `int[] someIntegers = {42};`, to the same result.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is an object in Java.

Also note that when you do `array.length` you're not invoking any methods but just accessing the array's `length` field. There are plenty of static methods in the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class.

Answer (score 5):

It would be important to note that arrays in Java have their own byte codes which they do not share with objects.  They are certainly Objects, but are handled slightly differently at the low level.

Answer (score 5):

1. An array is not an instance of any class listed in the class tree, however each array is an object and inherits directly from `java.util.Object`

```
(new int[1]) instanceof Object   // -> evaluates to true
```

2. The class `java.util.Arrays` is a helper class, and arrays are not instances of this class.

```
(new int[1]) instanceof java.util.Arrays    // -> compile error
```

3. The class `java.lang.reflect.Array` is a helper class, and arrays are not instances of this class.

```
(new int[1]) instanceof java.lang.reflect.Array    // -> compile error
```

4. Arrays inherit all the members of `java.lang.Object`
5. Arrays override the method `clone()` inherited from `Object`.
6. Arrays implement the field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array. length may be positive or zero.  It is `public` and `final`.
7. Arrays implement the interfaces `Cloneable` and `java.io.Serializable`.

8a. Arrays are supported by [`Class<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html).  You can retrieve the `Class<T>` instance from an array instance

```
(new int[2]).getClass()
```

or from an array type

```
int[].class
```

8b. A unique reflection class instance (ie an instance of `java.lang.Class<T>`) is created for each different array type in your code. Examples

```
int[].class.getCanonicalName()    //  -> "int[]"
String[].class.getCanonicalName() //  -> "java.lang.String[]" /
```

9. To repeat: Arrays are objects but are not instances of any class in the class tree.

---

REFERENCES

From the Java specification [Section 4.3.1 Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)

- *An object is a class instance or an array.*
- *A class instance is explicitly created by a class instance creation expression.*
- *An array is explicitly created by an array creation expression.*

From [java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

- *This class contains various methods for manipulating arrays (such as sorting and searching)*

From [java.lang.reflect.Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html)

- *The Array class provides static methods to dynamically create and access Java arrays.*

From [Section 10.1 Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

- *The direct superclass of an array type is `Object`.*
- *Every array type implements the interfaces `Cloneable` and `java.io.Serializable`.*

From [Section 10.7 Array Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

The members of an array type are all of the following:

- *The public final field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array. length may be positive or zero.*
- *The public method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the `clone` method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`.*
- *A clone of a multidimensional array is shallow, which is to say that it creates only a single new array. Subarrays are shared.*
- *All the members inherited from class Object; the only method of Object that is not inherited is its clone method.*

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add that arrays have a representation in the reflection API - [java.lang.reflect.Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would say the answer is yes, although I might add that, strictly speaking, an array is an object in C++ too. From §1.8 [intro.object] of the current standard (FDIS):

> An *object* is a region of storage.

Answer (score 1):

Every array in java is an object 
ex int[] a=new int [2]; So new is used to create an object and as it is an object we can check the class name just using a.getClass().getName();

Answer (score 1):

Arrays of anything are objects. One can call methods such as `equals`, `hashcode` etc:

```
final int[] i = {};
i.equals(new int[] {1});  // false
i.hashcode();
```

One cannot call methods on a native type.

Answer (score 1):

In java, arrays are objects, and are dynamically created. Arrays can be assigned to variables of type Object, and all methods of type Object can be invoked on arrays. An array can contain multiple variables or also contain 0 variables in which case it is said to be empty.

Comment: I did not get this part "all methods of type Object can be invoked on arrays". Could you please give an example of it?

Comment: @codeogeek A method is a block of code which only runs when it is called. You can pass data, known as parameters, into a method, they are used to perform certain actions. For example the toString() method converts an array into string representation. 

``` Student[] arr = { new Student(111, "bbbb", "london"), new Student(131, "aaaa", "nyc"), new Student(121, "cccc", "jaipur") }; 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr))```
Output: [111 bbbb london, 131 aaaa nyc, 121 cccc jaipur]

Answer (score 0):

Observe below code snippet and output.

```
public class Tester {
int a[];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Tester().a);// null
    System.out.println(new Tester().a[0]);// Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException \n at mainclass.Tester.main(Tester.java:10)
}
```

}

clearly array ***a*** is treated as object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) say so:

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type.

Note that array types of primitive types (like `int[]` or `char[]`) themselves are also objects.

Every array directly extends `java.lang.Object` and implements the interfaces `javs.lang.Cloneable` and `java.io.Serializable`. The runtime type signature of an array is `[L` immediately followed class name of component type (e.g. `[Ljava.lang.String`). Arrays of primitive types have the following runtime signature:

- `[B` for `byte[]`;
- `[S` for `short[]`;
- `[I` for `int[]`;
- `[J` for `long[]`;
- `[F` for `float[]`;
- `[D` for `double[]`;
- `[C` for `char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggested checking the value returned by instance of. I think that manner is semantically wrong because once you are able to write and compile such code:

```
    int[] myArray = new int[3];
    if (myArray instanceof Object) {
    }
```

It already proved that myArray is an object. If it were not, the code won't compile. As is written in a oracle tutorial

> The instanceof operator compares an ***object*** to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface