# Is int[] an object?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Had a look, and I can't seem to find a question that is the same as this. My question is about `int[]` in Java.

When you create an `int[]`, you use this syntax:

```
int[] x = new int[5];
```

The methods that are part of `int[]` also make me think it's an `Object`, but it doesn't follow the Java naming convention for classes, which is what's confusing me. It is also an array of a primitive type, which can be used like a primitive.

Is an `int[]` (or any primitive array I guess) an object, or a primitive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781022/is-an-array-an-object-in-java

Comment: Well that settles that one. Swiftly closing!

Comment: `System.out.println(x instanceof Object);` gives `true` =)

Comment: _It is also an array of a primitive type, which can be used like a primitive._ Careful how you say that It seems like you're saying the array can be used like a primitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An array in Java is a subclass of `Object`, therefore it's an object type - even if it contains primitive types. You can check this:

```
int[] x = new int[5];
if (x instanceof Object)
    System.out.println("It's an Object!");
```

Answer (score 3):

All arrays in Java are considered objects.  You can see this [in the Java Language Specification, Ch. 10:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

> In the Java programming language, **arrays are objects** (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

The type `int[]` is a subclass of `Object` that has all the method from `Object`.  Although syntactically it looks different from other object types (e.g. the name has a primitive type listed in it and there's no class definition), the Java language does consider them objects.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

"An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type.".This is how array is defined in [oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).So not only primitive array but also object array is a Object itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] x = new int[5];

Object a=(Object)x;

int[] y= (int[])a;
```

Comment: This isn't helpful and only points out what the user was asking.  It doesn't really answer their question.