# Is there a class to an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, oop

We know that Arrays are objects in Java. I believe to create an `object` in `Object oriented languages`(if not we can have it in a separate discussion), we need a blueprint of it(a class). But I'm not sure or cannot find the class for which the object is being created for arrays when the `new operator` is used. If there is a class for arrays in java, then how will the hierarchy look like?

If there is no class, then how are the objects instantiated? And what is the reason behind having an object type without a class?

Comment: ay89: I know that the arrays are objects in java. But I want to know if there is a benefit in having an object without a class(if there is one) for it.

Comment: Question starts with "We know that Arrays are objects in Java.", then people duplicate it to a question titled "Is an array an object in java". Hilarious.

Comment: auselen: you are right :)

Comment: Down-voter: Can I know why my question is down-voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are created by **virtual machine** with a special instruction called **newarray**, so think them as a special construct.

From [JVM Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.9):

> > 3.9. Arrays
> >
> > Java Virtual Machine arrays are also objects. Arrays are created and manipulated using a distinct set of instructions. The *newarray* instruction is used to create an array of a numeric type. The code:

Also read  more from [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) for class hierarchy of an array.

> > The direct superclass of an array type is Object.

Answer (score 2):

An array, let's say an `Object[]`, is a special kind of variable, just as primitives are. Its type is `Object[]`, not `Object`. Java is not a "fully" object oriented language, such as Ruby is; it has some special data types like arrays and primitives.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is reverse to your.

[An object is a class instance or an array.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8781051/390695)

But as Java is OOP language, everything must be represented as object. When you reflect your code you can use class  [java.lang.reflect.Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) that represent Array.

Answer (score 1):

*arrays are not primitive in java.* An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type.

> System.out.print(int[].class.toString());

It successfully prints and proves it has a concrete `class` in background and same applied for all other array types.

[Find documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java has classes for arrays, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8 Class Objects for Arrays, e.g.

```
Class<int[]> cls = int[].class;
```

These classes are dynamically created by JVM.

There is no hierarchy among arrays of primitive types

```
   int[] a = new long[1];
```

Produces compile time error. The hiearchy of Object array types is the same as with Object types

```
Object[] a = new String[1];
```