# Why does a float fit in a double but a float[] doesn't fit a double[]?

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

If I have a function that takes a `double` as an argument, I can easily put in a `float`.

However when I have a funcion that takes a `double[]` then I cannot pass a `float[]`.

```
public static void doSomethingWithMyDoubles(double[] doubles) {
    //....
}

public static void doSomethingWithMyDouble(double doubles) {
    //....
}

public static void main() {
    float floater = 10f;
    double doubler = 10d;

    doSomethingWithMyDouble(doubler) // OK
    doSomethingWithMyDouble(floater) // OK

    float[] floates = new float[10];
    double[] doubles = new double[10];

    doSomethingWithMyDoubles(doubles) // OK
    doSomethingWithMyDoubles(floates) // NOK
}
```

Comment: The best is to forget about `float` and behave as if there was only `double`.

Comment: Lol! If only there were no such things/people as embedded software/programmers :)

Comment: don't tell me my car uses float?

Comment: I didn't say I was working on a car, but it might depending on the type and age I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, arrays are not a primitive data type; instead they are of type [Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8781051/2970947). As a consequence, you cannot convert an array of one primitive type to an array of another primitive type directly (even though you might cast the individual elements in the array to the other type).

Comment: Well, not for primitives. A `String[]` can still be used as an `Object[]` for example...

Comment: Not entirely true, because you can cast an Object[] to a String[], just like you can cast an Object to a String. But you cannot cast a float[] to a double[] like you can cast a float to a double.

Comment: @JonSkeet Edited for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is because implicite type conversion takes place when you pass float value into the method whitch requires double one. But there is no type conversion between float[] and double[] arrays.

Answer (score 2):

A `float` is a 4-byte type, and a `double` is an 8-byte type.  Widening a single `float` to a `double` is a constant-time operation.  However, widening a `float[]` to a `double[]` has to do a full copy, and needs to take linear time to widen the entire array.  So Java won't do it implicitly -- it won't pretend that the operation is as cheap as an O(1) operation.

Answer (score 0):

That is because float and doubles are primitives. Floats can be automatically casted into doubles. However, double[] and float[] are objects. Try explicitly casting. You may need to iterate and cast each element and insert into your new array.