# Assignining one array to other which are diffrent in size in java

Tags: java

Given code:

```
float []    f3 = {2.7f};
float [] [] f2 = {{42.0f}, {1.7f, 1.9f}};
```

What should I understand by statement `if(f2[1]==f3)`? The result is `false`, but are we comparing their sizes?

Comment: `==` is referential equality. `a == b` is true only if `a` and `b` are *the same reference*. It doesn't matter how big they are or what's in them.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing references, because in Java [*arrays are objects*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8781051/2670792):
Since these are different objects, you will get `false`.

If you had this:

```
int[] f3 = { 100 };
int[][] f2 = { f3, { 2, 1 } };

System.out.println(f2[0] == f3);
```

The output would be `true` because you are adding the reference `f3` as an element of the array `f2`.

Answer (score 0):

`f2[1] == f3` compares references to different `float[]` instances and it will never return true. Use `Arrays.equals` instead

Answer (score 0):

`f2[1]==f3` tests if `f2[1]` points to the same address as `f3`. Thus even if you write

```
float [] f3={1.7f,1.9f};
float [] [] f2={{42.0f},{1.7f,1.9f}};
```

it will still come back false. Only if you assign

```
f2[1] = f3;
```

or vice versa `f2[1]==f3` will be true.