# If arrays are object in java why the assignment between arrays is deep copy

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

If arrays are object as stated in [Is an array an object in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781022/is-an-array-an-object-in-java) then why the output of the code snipped below is [1,1,1]?

I thought after the execution of statement "a=b;" a and b are still pointing to the same content! Isn't it supposed to be shadow copy between objects?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Local {
    int [] a = null;
    public Local(){
    int [] b = {1,1,1};
    int [] c = {5,5};
    a=b;
    b=c;// 'a' should change too as a and b are both objects! right?
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Local local = new Local();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(local.a));
    }

}
```

Comment: it is because you create a `new` int that makes it another object. a would retain its value and b will have a `new int`

Comment: @Kerppag What about now that I changed "b=new" to "b=c"?

Comment: it is the same concept. since `c` is stored differently in memory a will retain the b's content. and thus c is another new int. as you notice if you use b[0] = 2; the output of a would be [2,1,1]; since a and b are pointing in the same array

Comment: @Cgraphics even when you change to b=c you are actually making b to refer to whatever array object c refers to but with this you are not telling a to refer to whatever b is referring. Reference is to objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to explain it line per line:

```
int [] b = {1,1,1};
```

[image]

On this line, three things happened.

1. Created a variable named `b`.
2. Created an array of `int` `{1,1,1}`
3. Assigned `b` to the array of `int`created on step 2.

`int [] c = {5,5};`

[image]

Same thing happened here

1. Created a variable named `c`.
2. Created an array of `int` `{5,5}`
3. Assigned `c` to the array of `int` created on step 2.

`a=b;`

Now we also assigned `a` to whatever the **value** of `b` is, which in this case is the array of `int` `{1,1,1}`

Now we have something like

[image]

```
b=c; // 'a' should change too as a and b are both objects! right?
```

What happened here is that we assigned `b` to whatever `c`*'s* **value** is (`int` array `{5,5}`), now `b` is not pointing to `{1,1,1}` anymore and since Java is **pass by value**, `a`*'s* value remained. It's not like `a` is pointing to the **reference** of `b` that whatever `b` is pointing to, `a` will point to it too.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
// 'a' should change too as a and b are both objects! right?
```

No both `a` and `b` are just reference variables pointing to the same array object `{1,1,1}`.

With the below line you are making `b` to refer to altogether different array object where as `a` would still be pointing to the same array object `{1,1,1}` as the reference of only `b` but not `a`  is  changed by executing the below line

```
b = new int[] {2, 2};
```

Also by making `a = b` you are making them point to one single array object `{1,1,1}` and there is no deep/shallow copy happening here.

Answer (score 1):

the variable a would not automatically update itself. mainly because

```
b = c //is like b = new int[]{5,5};
```

it is the same concept in your question earlier with

```
b = new int[]{2,2,2};
```

`a` is pointing to `b's` int array which is [1,1,1]

and you are telling `b` to point to `c` which is [5,5]

```
a => b's array
b => c's array
```

so `a` will retain its object and `b` will have a new one.

Answer (score 0):

At first, b is pointed to the array object `{1,1,1}`
and you assign `b` to a, so `a` is pointed to `{1,1,1}`
so the out is {1,1,1}