# Why are we able to assign arrays to reference of type Object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

As part of learning, here is the pathological example below that am trying to understand,

```
class C{}; interface I{}; class S extends C implements I{};
class B{};
```

With these declarations, I can say that, `class C`    `class B` are immediate subclass of `Object` class and can access all methods of `Object` class from within those classes. But,

1)    When i declare `interface I{};` How is `interface I` related to `Object` class?

In continuation, Below are some assignment to array types, followed by subclass to super class assignment and vice-verse.

```
C[] c = new C[4];
S[] s = new S[6];
I[] i = new S[0];
B[] b = new B[2];

//i = new C[2]; Compile error
i =s; c=s; s = (S[])c; i = (I[])c;
i = (I[])b;  //Run-time error
```

I learnt that arrays are 'first class objects' and immediate subclass of `Object` class,

```
Object o = c;  // i mean `I i = c;` will not work `I[] i =c;` works
```

2) With respect to above definition(syntax), What is the meaning of 'arrays are first class objects'?Because `Object[] oa = c;` make sense to me as `class C` is immediate subclass of `Object` class.

Comment: for your second question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781022/is-an-array-an-object-in-java

Comment: Think of arrays as an internal class which extends (like any other classes in Java) the `Object` class.

Comment: @NoDataFound Despite i consider arrays as internal class, How would i consider reference variable `o` pointing to array `c`? Is it something like, python functions can be assigned to any name? Because after you assign to `o`, you have to again cast back back to array type to use `c`?

Comment: Don't be confused by runtime type and compile type. If you downcast your array to an Object, it is an Object for the compiler. But at runtime, it still be a `I[]`. You can test it by doing this: `System.out.println(o.getClass());` (will print `L[I` or something like that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When i declare interface I{}; How is interface I related to Object class?

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2):

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the **interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object**, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

> How would i consider reference variable o pointing to array c

As stated in the comments, the **array** is itself a subclass of `Object`, so the following assignment is valid:

```
Object o = c;
```

The relevant part from the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) says:

> In the Java programming language, **arrays are objects** (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, **and may be assigned to variables of type Object** (§4.3.2).

This is also what is meant by "arrays are first class objects". In Java, an array is not a special type or some special construct - it is essentially a sub class of `Object` with additional fields (in particular `length`) (and some additional compiler support to be able to syntactically describe and initialize an array).

Comment: why java is allowing to assign arrays to variables of type `Object`? Because to use that array again we need to typecast back to an array something like `c = (C[])o;` if we are typecasting back to array, then how arrays are first class objects?

Comment: Essentially because the language designers decided so, by making it a sub class of `Object`. This allows to pass around arrays as Objects, while casting them back to the array when necessary. Today you should probably use `ArrayList`, btw.

Comment: Andreas, One more point, as you said, In java, an array is not a special type but a subclass of `Object` class, but we also say, `An object is a class instance or an array.` How do i relate these two points?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question right, but `An array is a subclass of Object class` and `An object is a class instance or an array` are the same from an inheritance perspective - the first statement views the inheritance from the sub classes point of view (`array`), the second statement views the inheritance from the super classes point of view (`Object`)

Comment: super class point of view: Do you mean, instance of `Object` class is nothing but a class instance or an array?