# Why is list.toArray() an object while converting ArrayList to String[]?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

To make it very clear this is not a duplicate of these questions [Convert ArrayList to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string) and [Convert ArrayList containing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/convert-arraylist-containing-strings-to-an-array-of-strings-in-java?lq=1) but it is of relevance to them. 
Suppose we have a conversion method from `ArrayList` to `String []` as described in answers of the first link I've referred to:

```
List<String> stockList = new ArrayList<String>();
stockList.add("stock1");
stockList.add("stock2");

String[] stockArr = new String[stockList.size()];
stockArr = stockList.toArray(stockArr);

for(String s : stockArr)
   System.out.println(s);
```

With the print statement my output would look like this:

```
stock1
stock2
```

But what if I wanted my output to be in an array format (like `[stock1,stock2]`) and I excluded the conversion to `String`, i.e, the for loop towards the end.

If I would print out just the `String[]` it would give me a garbage value like `[Ljava.lang.String;@5636bc0a`. This I guess is probably because of problems with the jvm returns `toArray` as an object.

Why is it this way and what is the work around for this?

I need a `String []` that gives me a meaningful value. I need it in this format because I am using this conversion to call a JAX-WS function in my project which accepts only `String[]` values:

```
myJaxWSObj.setValue(String[] myArrayOfStrings);
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers, but some of you must have misunderstood the question. I want to convert ArrayList to String[] and not to String. So doing any sort of `.toString()` wouldn't help me much because as I mentioned above I need to call a JAX-WS class which accepts only `String[]` values. So the problem is not with `System.out.println()`.

Suppose I do a `.toString()` conversion I would need to convert it back to `String[]` by doing something like `stockArr.split("")`. I wanted to know if there is another work around for that.

**EDIT 2**

This has nothing to do with printing Arrays, it has to do with conversion of List to an Array of Strings.

Comment: So what you want is a way to print out meaningful information if the value is a `String[]`?  Like, if you were doing `System.out.println(stockArr)`, you want the contents of the array to show up?

Comment: Yes exactly, instead of values like `[Ljava.lang.String;@5636bc0a` and so on.

Comment: Does this *only* apply when you're using `System.out.println`?

Comment: The proper way to String[] from list is list.toArray(new String[list.size()]) Therefore you should do String sockArry = list.toArray(new String[list.size()])

Comment: @Makoto no it does not apply only to `System.out.println` and @YaWang that would still return object values.

Comment: Okay, that's good to know.  I'll go ahead and retract my dupe vote.  But, this raises the question:  what the heck is wrong with `toArray(String[] arr)`?

Comment: Thanks, that is the main problem `toArray(String[] arr)` returns object values and not string values.

Comment: I don't buy that.  Try using `String[] stockArr = stockList.toArray(new String[stockList.size()]);` instead.  You're *guaranteed* to get back the type of array you specify as the parameter to `toArray`, so you wouldn't get back an `Object[]` unless you were newing up an `Object[]`.

Comment: Did you try compiling what you just wrote?

Comment: I understand even less what you're asking about now. That `toArray` method is the appropriate way to get an array from a `List`.

Comment: Are you trying to parse text and marshall it into a `String[]`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. All I want is my output of String[] should look like for example [1,2,3...] because I need it to set the value of a JAX-WS Holder.

Comment: This is very frustrating. You say _that's exactly it_ (concerning the deserialization), but then you go and describe that you need the exact opposite process, ie. the serialization. Which one is it? And why doesn't `Arrays.toString()` solve your problem? That takes a `String[]` and returns a `String` that looks like `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects. Printing them using `System.out.println()` will call the default `Object#toString()` method which returns the object class name with a hashcode value. To print the string representation of an array, use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])):

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, they are converted to strings by the `Object.toString()` method inherited from Object, which describes their identities rather than their contents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not what I am looking for, hope the edit makes it more clear now.

Comment: @agenthost An array is not a string. These are two different types. You don't have to convert the array to a string to pass it to the function. Just make sure that whoever is going to print the values does this by using `Arrays.toString(array)`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with printing the values!

Comment: @agenthost I think you should re-read my answer. [An array is an object in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781022/is-an-array-an-object-in-java). That's why `toArray(String[] arr)` effectively returns an _object_. The value you saw `[Ljava.lang.String;@5636bc0a` is just the representation of this array _as an object_ but it doesn't mean it does not contain string values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful library function `Arrays.toString(arr)`

```
String[] arr = { "a", "b" };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
//Output: [a, b]
```

Comment: The question has changed a bit since I posted this answer