# Why it is possible to create collection of array of primitives but not collection of primitives

Tags: java

Java does not support creating a collection out of primitives, so following construct gives compilation error ("The argument can not be of primitive type):

```
 List<int> ints = new ArrayList<int>();
```

On the other hand creating a collection of arrays or primitives is allowed, so following construct is ok:

```
List<int[]> ints = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

What is a logic behind this?

---

Edit: The question is really about the array of primitives, not the primitives, so please don't explain me why can't I store primitives in collection, but rather why can I story array of primitives inside a collection?

Comment: Because an array is an object, not a primitive.

Comment: @Axel: Where it is said that array of primitives is an object?

Comment: @BackSlash: This is not really the answer, it does not say wheather array of primitives is object or not.

Comment: An array is an object regardless of whether it holds objects or primitives

Comment: @MarkKeen: Where is it defined?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8781051/4252352

Comment: It's fantastic how admins tend to mark question on stackoverflow as duplicates without really understanding them

Comment: @MarkKeen: Thans for your link. Actually it finally pointed me to the actual reference [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html ] where it is said that (as you and Axel wrote array is Object). This actually answers my question, Thanks

Comment: @walkeros did my answer help you? If yes, please mark it as an answer. Otherwise, maybe it's time to launch your first bounty?

Comment: xenteros: I already added a comment under your answer. But the real answer was given in a comment by Mark Keen. I'm willing to accept this as an answer but @MarkKeen would have to put it as an answer.

Comment: Although I knew the answer the credit has to go to the Paul (on link I provided) as this has already been answered before - why I didn't duplicate as an answer.  Personally @xenteros answer, with the edit, appears to answer your initial question - so mark as correct if you wish (I up voted myself). Although it was already answered in comments before the edit, but thats just semantics ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an array an object in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781022/is-an-array-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object is a class instance or an array. The Java Language Specification mentions: In the Java programming language arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). **All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array**.

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#:~:text=In%20the%20Java%20programming%20language,be%20invoked%20on%20an%20array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Java%20programming%20language,be%20invoked%20on%20an%20array).

Hence arrays can be used with Collections.

Answer (score 6):

Collections are generic: `Collection<T>`. `T` must be reference type. Primitives aren't reference types. On the other hand, array of primitives is a reference type so you can put it to `Collection`. Remember, that every primitive has it's wrapper class which can be passed as a type to generic type.

According to the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4):

```
Type:
    PrimitiveType
    ReferenceType
```

> A class is generic if it declares one or more type variables (§4.4).

#

> 4.3.1. Objects
>   An object is a class instance or an array.

#

> 4.4. Type Variables
>   A type variable is an unqualified identifier used as a type in class, interface, method, and constructor bodies.

Comment: That's true, however this is not complete answer I think, since generics live only until compilation time. In fact if you dony use generic type you can write something like:     `List a = new ArrayList();
    a.add(new int[0]);  a.add(0);`. The first will be stored as array itself and the second will be autoboxed and NOT stored as a primitive.