# Why are parentheses not used when creating an array?

Tags: java

**Java**

When creating an array using the `new` keyword, why are parentheses not used, given that [an array is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781022/is-an-array-an-object-in-java)?

```
int [] arr= new int[5];
```

Comment: Because the designers of Java chose to use a syntax that would be familiar to C(++) developers. That's also why you can write `int[] arr` **or** `int arr[]`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Are arrays the only exceptions to new objects being created (using the new keyword) using parentheses?

Comment: No. There's also autoboxing. `Integer i = 1;` **and** `String`(s). `String a = "Hello";`

Comment: It is also because they would be redundant. The compiler already knows it is an array-creation expression, and that there will never be any arguments, so there is no point in requiring them.