# Objects in array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java, I was reading Head first Java when I came across object in arrays. The code is from the book itself, I get the flow of the code but I don't really understand the second line. What does `new Dog[7]` do, in the book it says

"Declare and Create a Dog array to hold 7 Dog references"

If we have already created dog references why do we need to create a dog reference for individual array items again.

```
Dog[] pets;
pets = new Dog[7];
pets[0] = new Dog();
```

Comment: `new Dog[7]` creates an *empty* array of `Dog`, that is `[null, null, null, null, null, null, null]`. You still need to assign an actual instance for each index of the array.

Comment: a `Dog[]` is capable of *holding* `Dog` references; `pets = new Dog[7];` holds no references yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between declaration and initialization.
`Dog[] pets` declares that the variable `pets` is an array of `Dogs`
`pets = new Dog[7]` initializes the variable `pets`, it assigns it a value. The value is an array of size 7 full of null references.

It is the same for primitives :

```
int i; //declaration
i = 5; //initialization
```

As well as you can write

```
int i = 5;
```

you can write

```
Dog[] pets = new Dog[7];
```

In this case, you do the declaration and initialization on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Before the second line, you just say that the variable `pets` exists, and it's an array of `Dog`, but the array doesn't exist in memory, because it hasn't been created.

In order to be able to use the array and read / store values inside, you need to actually create this array in memory, which is what the 2nd line does: it creates an array of `Dog`, of size 7.

Answer (score 1):

The first line declares a variable of a "Dog array" type. The second line actually initializes it with an array that has seven slots, each of which are `null`. The third line creates an actual Dog instance, and assigns it to the first slot of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dog[] pets;
```

This will declare an array of `dog`. But when you do `pets = new Dog[7];` it will initialize array with length of 7.

```
pets[0] = new Dog();
```

this statement will store an object of dog at 0th position.

Answer (score 1):

This line `pets = new Dog[7];` creates a Array Object which will contain `Dog` objects.
So initially all 7 indeces in pets array are `null`. Therefore `pets[0] = new Dog();` required to create `Dog` Objects

Answer (score 0):

Every object in [java](/questions/tagged/java) must be initialized with the keyword `new`, which allocates memory on the heap.

Arrays in `java` are also objects, thus they must be initialized with `new`.

By default, every object in the array will have a `null` value. So you must initialize every individual item with the `new` keyword again.

Situation at each step:

```
 Dog[] pets;            // <-- reference to an array of Dog, still uninitialized
 pets = new Dog[7];     // <-- now pets points to an array of 7 Dog's. Array value is [null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
 pets[0] = new Dog();   // <-- array now is [Dog@some_memory_address, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

---

See the oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for arrays

Comment: You don't always need a new keyword for an array. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227778/ways-of-using-array-in-java

Comment: @MrakVladar that is just a shorthand. Under the hoods, the memory is till initialized with `new`

Answer (score 0):

With that you are declaring and creating a java array able to contain 7 items of dog type. From a machine stand point you are creating a pointer to the memory space to contain your objects.

Answer (score 0):

`Dog[] pets;` : decalres the array of `Dog`
`pets = new Dog[7];` : Creates an array (with contiguous memory allocation on heap) of `Dog` to hold 7 `Dog` references (initially `null`).